# JavaScript, '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript, get

I'm a very beginner, I want to my JavaScript code to pick up a random line in a text document, and then to display it. I already found an answer on the forum, which is that:

```
//This loads your file from somewhere
$.get( "Premium.txt", function( data ) {
  //Split data by lines if its in a formatted format (like json you have to decode or parse the data)
  var lines = data.split("/n");

  //Random item number
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

  //Get random line
  var line = lines[r];

  console.log(line);
});
```

When I run the code, it says that '$' is undefined. I don't know what to do, I don't know what '$' means. If someone can help.

Comment: well `$` is jQuery so you do not have jQuery included. I would just use fetch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Oh and btw it would be `\n` and not `/n`!

Comment: Try adding this script to your code <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 3):

That code is using jQuery, specifically [this method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). To you it, you have to include jQuery in your page. See https://learn.jquery.com/ for more about that.

But you don't *need* jQuery to do a GET, you can use `fetch`, which is built into modern browsers:

```
fetch("Premium.txt")
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(data) {
    //Split data by lines if its in a formated format (like json you have to decode or parse the data)
    var lines = data.split("\n");

    //Random item number
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

    //Get random line
    var line = lines[r];

    console.log(line);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Handle/report the fact an error occurred
});
```

The code in your question was only using JavaScript features that were in ES5 and earlier, so I've stayed with that above. But in modern environments you could use features from ES2015+ (although in this simple code it makes very little difference), like this:

```
fetch("Premium.txt")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(data => {
    //Split data by lines if its in a formated format (like json you have to decode or parse the data)
    const lines = data.split("\n");

    //Random item number
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

    //Get random line
    const line = lines[r];

    console.log(line);
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report the fact an error occurred
});
```

---

Also note that `"/n"` should be `"\n"` (`/` and `\`) mean very different things in JavaScript), I've updated it in the above.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, maybe I don't run the code the way it should be done, but it doesn't know what's "fetch". It displays an undefined error :/

Comment: If you use IE11, then that might be the cause, because IE11 doesn't "know" fetch. What browser or environment are you using?